# How to say "In his absence" and "Where is God" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am looking for the Latin translation of two phrases:
"In his absence" 
and 
"Where is God".

Comment: Please, tell us: how did you try to translate them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because translations requires to have tried to translate.

Comment: Did you want medieval, classical, or modern Latin? I recommend clarifying that and making an attempt and posting this question again. Don't worry about being wrong - it's a great chance to learn by doing and also one of the rules of the Community.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to phrase "in his absence" is the absolute ablative *eo absente*.
It can mean all kinds of things like "when/because/if he is absent", much like the English phrase.
There is a separate feminine version if you need her absence: *ea absente*.

The phrase "Where is X?" is simple: *Ubi est X?*
Now just put X = *Deus*.